# Terraform Cosmosdb multiple subnet

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-cosmosdb, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

**Terraform Cosmosdb multiple subnet**
Getting error when add additional subnet for cosmosdb

Terraform Error:

```
Error: Invalid value for module argument

  on manifests/backend.tf line 289, in module "cosmosdb_1":
 289:   vnet_subnet_id               = ["azurerm_subnet.backend.id", "azurerm_subnet.application.id", "azurerm_subnet.frontend.id"]

The given value is not suitable for child module variable "vnet_subnet_id"
defined at modules/cosmosdb/variable.tf:26,1-26: element 0: object required.
```

Configuration for main.tf defined variable for subnets

```
  dynamic "virtual_network_rule" {
    for_each = var.virtual_network_rule != null ? toset(var.virtual_network_rule) : []
    content {
      id                                   = [var.vnet_subnet_id]
      ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = virtual_network_rule.value.ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint
    }
  }
```

variable.tf file define variable type

```
variable "vnet_subnet_id" {
  type = list(object({
    id                                   = string,
    ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = bool
  }))
}
```

main configuration for vnet subnet defined in backend.tf

```
module "cosmosdb_1" {
  depends_on                   = [module.vnet]
  source                       = "./../modules/cosmosdb"
  cosmodb_account_name         = "${var.env}${var.cosmodb_account_name_1}"
  resource_group_name          = "${var.env}-bsai"
  ip_range_filter              = var.ip_range_filter
  location                     = "${var.region}"
  cosmosdb_name                = var.cosmosdb_name_1
  enable_automatic_failover    = var.enable_automatic_failover
  failover_location_secondary  = var.failover_location_secondary
  failover_priority_secondary  = var.failover_priority_secondary
  vnet_subnet_id               = ["azurerm_subnet.backend.id", "azurerm_subnet.application.id", "azurerm_subnet.frontend.id"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Module: main.tf

```
  dynamic "virtual_network_rule" {
    for_each = var.vnet_subnet_id
    content {
      id   = virtual_network_rule.value.id
      ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = true
    }
  }
```

variable.tf

```
variable "vnet_subnet_id" {
  description = "List of subnets to be used in Cosmosdb."
  type = list(object({
    id   = string
  }))
}
```

Backend.tf

```
vnet_subnet_id               = [{id   = azurerm_subnet.backend.id}, {id = azurerm_subnet.application.id}, {id = azurerm_subnet.frontend.id}]
```